# PySerial write errors (baudrate sensitive)

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, pyserial, uart

I'm having some issues with pyserial and windows (on linux it works fine with the same code); I seem to be writing erroneous bytes.

The code even works fine on the same machine inside a debian VM, So Im pretty sure its a software thing.

I'm using Python 2.7.6 32bit, pyserial 2.7 but have tried others (2.5 and 2.4) all exibit the same errors.

Interestingly enough, the errors are *much* less frequent when the baudrate is increased to 115200.

This is the relavant bit of my code:

```
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.timeout = 0.1
ser.port = "COM74" 
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.parity = "N"
ser.stopbits = 1
ser.open()

ser.write("AT+CMGR\r")
search("OK", 5, rec, ser)
ser.write("AT+CGSN\r")
search("OK", 5, rec, ser)
ser.write("AT+CSQ\r")
search("OK", 5, rec, ser)
ser.write("AT+CREG?\r")
search("OK", 5, rec, ser)

ser.close()
```

Which when tested gave the following output: (writing to an autobauding device with echo on):

```
***Timeout***, expected: "OK" received: "A\xa8+CMGR\r"
***Timeout***, expected: "OK" received: "AT+C\x87SN\r\r\nERROR\r\n"
***Timeout***, expected: "OK" received: "AT+CS\xd1\r"
***Timeout***, expected: "OK" received: "A\xa8+CREG?\r"
```

I can confirm that the stuff after "received:" (sans quotes and with the exception of the "ERROR" and some CR NL chars which are generated by the device) is what is actually received by the device:

```
A\xa8+CMGR\r
AT+C\x87SN\r
AT+CS\xd1\r
A\xa8+CREG?\r
```

If anyone can suggest a fix I would be grapefruit

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the AT commands with windows and Serial and i don't have these problems, my guess is that it's has something to do with encoding.

Can you please try this [AT Commander](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/module-tester/)

Try to connect your device and to see whether you get the right response if it's the same then the problem is at your device.

Comment: The problem is categorically not the device, the script works fine over Linux to the same device, and via minicom/screen the device communicates normally.