# How can I fix the error "cannot import name 'serial' from 'serial' (unknown location)"?

Tags: python, pyserial, serial-communication

In my code I try to interact with some equipment using the `serial` module:

```py
from serial import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port

print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used

ser.write(b'hello')     # write a string

ser.close()
```

But I get this error:

```
cannot import name 'serial' from 'serial' (unknown location)
```

I searched on Stack Overflow for this error message but I could not find an answer which resolves my problem.

Based on what I found, I tried:

- `pip install serial`,
- `pip install pyserial`,
- and also unistall and reinstall.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I would like to know what you uninstall and reinstalled. Serial and Pyserial from my experience , these both cant get along that installed together. either one have to go.

Comment: It may be just using correct case:  Try `from serial import Serial` and when you use it, use: `ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0') # open serial port`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python serial without pyserial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542858/python-serial-without-pyserial)

Comment: @RufusVS Thanks for your command But I'm can't understand what you said. That mean is right? or something need to fix?  ++ Aha! I try to this now

Comment: @JohnMelodyMelissa Thanks to your answer. But I've already installed and uninstalled it both together...And I saw the linked qeustion but It;s little bit different with my problem.. I reallty appreciate.

Comment: Actually like I mentioned previously, You cant use serial and pyserial together(this confuses the compiler). Either you use one or the other. usually I use ```pip3 install serial``` and COMPLETELY (I mean COMPLETELY) uninstall pyserial. ```sudo pip3 uninstall pyserial```  


alternatively, You can download from the source and install it at the {directory} of your pip will be.

This from my experience of the same problem.

Comment: else you can compile it from the [Source] (https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial) and copy it to your pip {directory}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
from serial import Serial  # note the capital S change

ser = Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port

print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used

ser.write(b'hello')     # write a string

ser.close()
```

Comment: OMG Master Rufus!! I got solution from you :). How can I express this pleasure I'm really Thanks for your help. Could I question one more? What is different between Serial and serial.Sreial?

Comment: if you  import using  `from serial import Serial`, it puts the Serial class into your name space so you can use it as I show.  if you imported the module using: `import serial`, to use the class you would need `ser = serial.Serial(...`

Comment: AHA!! I really appreciate sir. I have to study more step by step @@!!